# GROUP or DISTINCT after JOIN returns duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, distinct

I have two tables, `products` and `meta`. They are in relation 1:N where each product row has at least one meta row via foreign key.

(viz. SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8f34/1)

I need to join these two tables but i need to filter only unique products. When I try this query, everything is ok (4 rows returned):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(product_id)
FROM meta JOIN products ON products.id = meta.product_id
```

but when I try to select all columns the DISTINCT rule no longer applies to results, as 8 rows instead of 4 is returned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(product_id), *
FROM meta JOIN products ON products.id = meta.product_id
```

I have tried many approaches like trying to `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` on sub-query but always with same result.

Comment: Which 4 from the 8 rows in META would you like to return? Any? What is the criteria?

Comment: I mean, product_id #1 has 3 corresponding rows in meta. Which one?

Comment: Oops, i forgot to add it, i need for example the one meta with latest date in my real case but there it could be just only the meta with highest id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While retrieving all or most rows from a table, the fastest way for this type of query typically is to aggregate / disambiguate *first* and join *later*:

```
SELECT *
FROM   products p
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) *
   FROM   meta
   ORDER  BY product_id, id DESC
   ) m ON m.product_id = p.id;
```

The more rows in `meta` per row in `products`, the bigger the impact on performance.

Of course, you'll want to add an `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery do define *which* row to pick form each set in the subquery. @Craig and @Clodoaldo already told you about that. I am returning the `meta` row with the highest `id`.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8f34/39)

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Optimize performance

Still, this is not always the fastest solution. Depending on data distribution there are various other query styles. For this simple case involving another join, this one ran considerably faster in a test with big tables:

```
SELECT p.*, sub.meta_id, m.product_id, m.price, m.flag
FROM  (
   SELECT product_id, max(id) AS meta_id
   FROM   meta
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
JOIN meta     m ON m.id = sub.meta_id
JOIN products p ON p.id = sub.product_id;
```

If you wouldn't use the non-descriptive `id` as column names, we would not run into naming collisions and could simply write `SELECT p.*, m.*`. (I *never* use `id` as column name.)

If performance is your paramount requirement, consider more options:

- a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) with pre-aggregated data from `meta`, if your data does not change (much).
- a recursive CTE emulating a [**loose index scan**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) for a *big* `meta` table with *many* rows per product (relatively few distinct `product_id`).
  This is the only way I know to use an index for a DISTINCT query over the whole table.

Comment: Since the `distinct` is `on` a META column I would guess the planner is smart enough to do it first by himself. Am I unreazonable optimistic?

Comment: Answering my own question after checking the `explain` output. No it is not smart enough

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Yep, that's what my tests keep showing, too - which is the sole reason for my added answer.

Comment: Your output is incomplete.  The meta.id column is missing as it would have a duplicate name.  Better to change to 'SELECT p.*, meta_id, m.* FROM....'.

Comment: @youngthing: `meta_id` is the same as `m.id` and would be redundant.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: have you tested it?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8f34/48 suggests otherwise..

Comment: @youngthing: That's because the name `id` is in the result twice and JDBC (which sqlfiddle is based on) swallows the second (bug!). The same does not happen in my tests with psql or pgAdmin. Wouldn't happen if we wouldn't use the non-descriptive `id` as column names (I ***never*** do this nonsense, but half-wit ORMs do.) Consider: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0a77d/3

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: agreed, looks like a bug IMHO in JDBC.  PostgreSQL produces two columns with the name 'id'.

Comment: Thank you (and others with same solution) but your answer is most explicit and i like both correct/optimized answers. And also, it is working as expected. I never heard of DISTINCT ON before, as I was using the MySQL and migrated to PgSQL recently. And as both my develop, test and production enviroments run PgSQL 9.* it's ok.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be looking for [`DISTINCT ON`, a PostgreSQL extension feature](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON(product_id)
  * 
FROM meta 
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = meta.product_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8f34/18

However, note that without an `ORDER BY` the results are not guaranteed to be consistent; the database can pick any row it wants from the matching rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use `distinct on` as suggested by [@Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25487276/131874) but combined with the `order by` clause as explicated in the comments. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8f34/35)

```
select distinct on(m.product_id) * 
from
    meta m
    inner join
    products p on p.id = m.product_id
order by m.product_id, m.id desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to identify the max(ID) for each product, then use that in the superquery to gather the details you want to display:

```
SELECT q.product_id, meta.* from
(SELECT product_id, max(meta.ID)
 FROM meta JOIN products ON products.id=meta.product_id 
 GROUP BY product_id) q 
JOIN meta ON q.max=meta.id;
```

It is not the only solution!

A quick comparison to use of DISTINCT ON solutions suggests that it is slower (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8f34/38).  It avoids a full sort on ID and prefers a sequential scan.

Comment: Edited to add a comparison to a "DISTINCT ON" strategy.

Comment: Your query exhibits two weak spots. 1. Does not return all columns from `products` like the question. 2. Slower than necessary. Aggregate *first*, join to products *later* (only good if most or all of `meta` is involved in the query). I added code to my answer, plus more on performance.

Comment: True.  I really like your solution, though I think it needs one adjustment to the output.