# Use id values from one query, to corresponding column with same id in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

This question is a bit vague and I do apologize, hopefully the example below will clear it up. It's a fairly elementary question, I just can't seem to quite find the right solution with my very limited knowledge and SQL relevant vocabulary

There is a table with people,

```
create table People (
id          integer, 
name        LongName,
primary key (id)
);
```

And one for workers that references people

```
create table Workers (
id          integer references People(id),
worktype    varchar(20),
primary key (id)
);
```

and lastly a works_for relationship

```
create table Works_for (
worker      integer references Workers(id),
employer    integer references Job(id),
primary key (worker,job)
);
```

Now what I want to do is get all people that work at least 20 jobs, so I get the correct list of id's with the following query:

```
SELECT worker
FROM Works_for
GROUP BY worker 
HAVING COUNT(worker) > 20;
```

However I also want to get the names of these workers. How would I go about this? I've tried a number of things but I keep running into errors. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You also want to get the name -- try using a couple of `joins`...

Comment: Yeah I was trying that before but couldn't get the syntax right... I'll keep trying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the tables and select both fields like this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.id
FROM People p
JOIN Works_for wf ON (p.id = wf.worker)
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(wf.worker) > 20;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd2da/6/0)

Comment: Very nice solution, couldn't quite figure out how to do the join but this makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT worker,name
FROM Works_for join People on worker=id
GROUP BY worker,name 
HAVING COUNT(employer) > 20;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e03e3/1
There will be no 20 but just 3 records but I think it's enough as a demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used billynoah's answer for my solution, but I ran across another problem and your solution worked better for that (probably mostly because I'm a terrible beginner but oh well) :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join:

```
select worker, name, worktype from
(select worker,MIN(employer) as employer 
from works_for group by worker having COUNT(worker)>20) w
left join People p on p.id = w.employer
left join Workers ws on  ws.id = w.worker
```

like this, you also get people name and work type

Answer (score 0):

#### Query

While working with your current schema:

```
SELECT id, p.name
FROM  (
   SELECT worker AS id
   FROM   works_for
   GROUP  BY 1 
   HAVING count(*) > 20
   ) wf
JOIN   people  p USING (id);
```

It's faster to aggregate and eliminate irrelevant rows first and *then* join. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.
`count(*)` is also a bit faster than `count(worker)`. It does the same as long as `worker` cannot be NULL, which is the case here.

There are many related answers:

- [GROUP or DISTINCT after JOIN returns duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486942/group-or-distinct-after-join-returns-duplicates/25487898#25487898)

#### Schema

Your presented table layout is odd. The `workers` table is a 1:1 extension to `people`. You might as well add the column `worktype` to `people` and drop the table `workers`. But it's a surprising limitation that a person can only have a single `worktype` ...

Typically, it would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, name      text NOT NULL  -- custom domain?
);

CREATE TABLE job (
  job_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, name   text NOT NULL
-- more
);

CREATE TABLE person_job (
  person_id   int REFERENCES person
, job_id      int REFERENCES job
, worktype_id int REFERENCES worktype
, PRIMARY KEY (person_id, job_id)
);
```

The type of work goes into `person_job` or the `job` table. Etc. More:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)