# Combining multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pivot, crosstab

I have a database structure in PostgreSQL that looks something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  medium  CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  works   CASCADE;
DROP DOMAIN IF EXISTS nameVal CASCADE;
DROP DOMAIN IF EXISTS numID   CASCADE;
DROP DOMAIN IF EXISTS alphaID CASCADE;

CREATE DOMAIN alphaID   AS VARCHAR(10);
CREATE DOMAIN numID     AS INT;
CREATE DOMAIN nameVal   AS VARCHAR(40);

CREATE TABLE works (
   w_alphaID    alphaID     NOT NULL,
   w_numID      numID       NOT NULL,
   w_title      nameVal     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(w_alphaID,w_numID));


CREATE TABLE medium (
   m_alphaID    alphaID     NOT NULL,
   m_numID      numID       NOT NULL,
   m_title      nameVal     NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY(m_alphaID,m_numID) REFERENCES 
      works ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO works VALUES('AB',1,'Sunset'),
                        ('CD',2,'Beach'),
                        ('EF',3,'Flower');

INSERT INTO medium VALUES('AB',1,'Wood'),
                         ('AB',1,'Oil'),
                         ('CD',2,'Canvas'),
                         ('CD',2,'Oil'),
                         ('CD',2,'Bronze'),
                         ('EF',3,'Paper'),
                         ('EF',3,'Pencil');
SELECT * FROM works;
SELECT * FROM medium;

SELECT w_alphaID AS alphaID, w_numID AS numID, w_title AS
       Name_of_work, m_title AS Material_used 
     FROM works, medium WHERE 
       works.w_alphaID = medium.m_alphaID 
       AND works.w_numID = medium.m_numID;
```

The output looks something like this:

```
 w_alphaid | w_numid | w_title 
-----------+---------+---------
 AB        |       1 | Sunset
 CD        |       2 | Beach
 EF        |       3 | Flower
(3 rows)

 m_alphaid | m_numid | m_title 
-----------+---------+---------
 AB        |       1 | Wood
 AB        |       1 | Oil
 CD        |       2 | Canvas
 CD        |       2 | Oil
 CD        |       2 | Bronze
 EF        |       3 | Paper
 EF        |       3 | Pencil
(7 rows)

 alphaid | numid | name_of_work | material_used 
---------+-------+--------------+---------------
 AB      |     1 | Sunset       | Wood
 AB      |     1 | Sunset       | Oil
 CD      |     2 | Beach        | Canvas
 CD      |     2 | Beach        | Oil
 CD      |     2 | Beach        | Bronze
 EF      |     3 | Flower       | Paper
 EF      |     3 | Flower       | Pencil
(7 rows)
```

Now my question is what query should I use to have the format of the last  `SELECT` statement to look something like this:

```
 alphaid | numid | name_of_work | material_used_1 | material_used_2 | material_used_3 
---------+-------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------
 AB      |     1 | Sunset       | Wood            | Oil             |
 CD      |     2 | Beach        | Canvas          | Oil             | Bronze
 EF      |     3 | Flower       | Paper           | Pencil          |
(3 rows)
```

I looked into using `string_agg()` but that puts the values into one cell but I am looking to have a separate cell for each value. I tried using join to see if I can achieve such output but with no success so far. I appreciate you taking the time to look at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be simpler with a simpler schema:

- No domain types (what's the purpose?)
- Add an actual PK to table `medium`
- Rather use a surrogate PKs (a `serial` column) instead of the multicolumn PK and FK over two domain types.
  Or at least use the same (simpler) column name for columns with the same content: just `alpha_id` instead of `m_alphaID` and `w_alphaID` etc.

That aside, here are solutions for your setup ***as is***:

#### True `crosstab()` solution

There are several specific difficulties for your [`crosstab()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) query:

- No single column that can serve as *row_name*.
- Multiple extra columns.
- No *category* column.
- No defined order for values (so I use arbitrary order instead).

Basics (**read this first!**):

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

For your special case:

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)
- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

Solution:

```
SELECT alphaid, numid, name_of_work, material_1, material_2, material_3
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT rn, w.alphaid, w.numid, w.name_of_work
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY rn) AS mat_nr  -- order undefined!
        , m_title AS Material_used 
   FROM  (
      SELECT w_alphaID AS alphaid, w_numID AS numid, w_title AS name_of_work
           , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY w_alphaID, w_numID) AS rn
       FROM  works
      ) w
   JOIN   medium m ON w.alphaid = m.m_alphaID 
                  AND w.numid   = m.m_numID
   ORDER  BY rn, mat_nr'
 , 'VALUES (1), (2), (3)'  -- add more ...
)
 AS ct (
    rn bigint, alphaid text, numid int, name_of_work text
  , material_1 text, material_2 text, material_3 text  -- add more ...
   );
```

#### Poor man's crosstab with standard SQL

If the additional module [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) cannot be installed or if top performance is not important, this simpler query does the same, slower:

```
SELECT w_alphaid AS alphaid, w_numid AS numid, w_title AS name_of_work
     , arr[1] AS material_used_1
     , arr[2] AS material_used_2
     , arr[3] AS material_used_3 -- add more?
FROM   works w
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT m_alphaid, m_numid, array_agg(m_title::text) AS arr
   FROM   medium
   GROUP  BY m_alphaid, m_numid
   ) m ON w.w_alphaid = m.m_alphaid 
      AND w.w_numid   = m.m_numid;
```

- The cast to `text` (or `varchar` ...) is necessary because there is no predefined array type for your custom domain. Alternatively you could define the missing array type.
- One subtle difference to the above: using `LEFT JOIN` here instead of just `JOIN` to preserve rows from `works` that have *no* related materials in `medium` at all.
- Since you return the whole table, it's cheaper to aggregate rows in `medium` *before* you join. For a small selection it might be cheaper to join first and *then aggregate*. Related:

  - [GROUP or DISTINCT after JOIN returns duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486942/group-or-distinct-after-join-returns-duplicates/25487898#25487898)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string_agg() in a subquery and then break the string into separate columns. See also this question on [how to split string into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns)

```
SELECT alphaID, numID, Name_of_Work
      ,split_part(Material_used, ',', 1) AS Material_used_1
      ,split_part(Material_used, ',', 2) AS Material_used_2
      ,split_part(Material_used, ',', 3) AS Material_used_3
      ,split_part(Material_used, ',', 4) AS Material_used_4
FROM (
    SELECT w_alphaID AS alphaID, w_numID AS numID, w_title AS Name_of_work,
           String_Agg( m_title, ',' ) AS Material_used 
    FROM works, medium 
    WHERE works.w_alphaID = medium.m_alphaID 
       AND works.w_numID = medium.m_numID 
    GROUP BY w_alphaID, w_numID, w_title ) t
```

Comment: The idea is solid. The required `GROUP BY` clause is missing though. And it's safer to work with an array instead of string concatenation. `m_title` might contain the separator used in `string_agg()`, which would lead to errors. I added a solution with `array_agg()` to my answer.